# Настройка плагина: Swiper

Tags: javascript, плагин, swiper

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, что бы соблюдался порядок?

1. В примере идет: 1,3,5,2,4,6
2. Необходимо: 1,2,3,4,5,6

Этот плагин: [Swiper API](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css">

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      height: 200px;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      slidesPerColumn: 2,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужен мультислайдер - то укажите как заполнять слайд слайдами, через опцию `slidesPerColumnFill:"row"`.

Вот рабочий пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css">

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      height: 200px;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
    <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
  
  
  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      slidesPerColumn: 2,
      slidesPerColumnFill:"row",
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```